# flask does not return JSON data using request.json

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, flask

I want to to send the text content of an input element as type json to flask and print out the value

but the output from print is `None`

to send the data I used the
JQuery post method

```
function upload_postdata() {
    let input_text = $("#input_element").val();
    return $.post('/upload_columns',{
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: input_text
    });
}
```

and the route is

```
@flask_class.route('/upload_columns', methods=['POST'])
def upload_columns():
    date_from = request.json #
    print(f"the name is{date_from}")
    return jsonify(" polo")
```

reading the docs
`request.json` should return parsed JSON data.

the Header section from the browser
tells me also

```
contentType: application/json
data: Marco
```

so why doe I get None as return
using `request.json`?

using `request.form['data']` gives me the correct output though

Comment: Did you print the `request.headers` on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. One is that you are mixing the syntax of `$.post` with that of `$.ajax`. `$.ajax` accepts `data` and `contentType` parameters as fields in an options object; `$.post` does things differently, and expects the data to be posted as the second parameter. Thus, you send no content type header, and your data is two fields, one of which is named `data`. This is why `request.form["data"]` reads it. It is not JSON, it is encoded in the URL encoding, something like:

```
contentType=application%2Fjson%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8&data=Marco
```

If you had used `$.ajax` instead, still it would not work, because jQuery does not automatically convert `data` into JSON, and `Marco` is not valid JSON — `"Marco"` is. To make the response into a valid JSON, you would need to use

```
data: JSON.stringify(input_text)
```

With this, the payload becomes simply

```
"Marco"
```

and it can't be parsed by `request.form["data"]` any more, but should give `Marco` using `request.json`.

Comment: using `JSON.stringify`  still return `None` on the flask view,  tested with `jQuery Ajax and  and post method, also  request.json()` with brakets is not  is not valid, returns a TypeError.

Comment: Yeah, typed all from head without testing. `.json` or `.get_json()`, not `.json()`. You can't get both `None` and a `TypeError` at the same time.